# Does Internet Explorer in latest Windows Phone OS support Plugins?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, plugins

The best I could find was a PDF about Windows Phone 7 stating that IE in WP 7 does not support Plugins [1].

I hope it still doesn't support Plugins ;-). I however need to verify this is still true.

[1] http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/5/93565816-AD4E-4448-B49B-457D07ABB991/Windows%20Internet%20Explorer%20Mobile%20on%20Windows%20Phone%207.pdf

Comment: plugins in browsers have been the cause of the majority of vulnerabilities in computers. REMOVING plugin support is a GOOD thing. plugins are evil, and these days, useless/stupid/pointless junk

Comment: I totally agree with you. But that was not the question.